# Retrieve MySQL result set grouped by month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table

```
Create table temp_table (
Tmp_id int(10) auto_increment,
paid tinyint default 0,
date_received DATETIME NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Tmp_id)
)
```

I want to query all records that have paid = 0, but I want it the result to be the months where paid = 0 evaluates to true.

For example, finance could see a short list of records, only showing the months necessary.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You'll have to have a month column to GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to get month and year:

```
SELECT YEAR(Date_Received) AS `Year`,
       MONTH(Date_Received) AS `Month`,
       COUNT(*) AS Records
FROM   Temp_Table
WHERE  Paid = 0
GROUP BY YEAR(Date_Received), MONTH(Date_Received);
```

Or if you want to keep it in date format, you could use:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Date_Received,'%Y-%m-01') AS MonthStart
FROM   Temp_Table
WHERE  Paid = 0
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(Date_Received,'%Y-%m-01');
```

This will simply turn all dates into the first of the month, so all records from November 2013 will show as 2013-11-01, this is handy if you want to send a date to your application layer so you can still manuplate it as a date (e.g change the language/display format).

Comment: This worked great. Is there a way to actually chose this as the solution?

Comment: I like the native function, this reduces my code work. Thanks Gareth !

Comment: [Click the green tick next to the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/179361), although [there is a 15 minute time limit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50697) which may not have elapsed yet.

Comment: there's a 15 minute time limit? that's stupid! What if the user doesn't read the answer until tomorrow? :( (edit: never mind i just read that it's 15 minute later) well that's still kind'a odd

Comment: I have a reputation limit that prevents me from voting for the answer. Marked it as the confirmed answer.